# Rails multiple nested resources edit link not adding primary resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, polymorphic-associations, nested-resources

I'm using multiple nested resources like so:

```
  resources :users do
    resources :clients do
      resources :positions
    end
  end

  resources :clients
  resources :positions
```

Everything is working and set up correctly in my models and controllers but I can't seem to figure out why this edit position link is not adding the user into the method name.

```
<%= link_to 'Edit Position', edit_polymorphic_path([@user, @client, @position]) %>
```

Only outputs this: `edit_client_position_path`

Instead of this: `edit_user_client_position_path`

It's as if the `:user_id` is not being taken into account, but if i remove the edit link from the show page at `http://127.0.0.1:3000/users/1/clients/1/positions/1` the page loads successfully. Any insight is very much appreciated!

---

**UPDATE**

I managed to get the link to work *almost* the way I want earlier. I modified my routes file like the following:

```
  resources :users do
    resources :clients do
      resources :positions
    end
  end

  resources :clients do
    resources :positions
  end

  resources :clients
  resources :positions
```

It now links to `/clients/1/positions/1/edit` instead of `/users/1/clients/1/positions/1/edit` so I think I'm on the right track. I know someone commented looking for an answer so hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try

`edit_user_client_position_path(@user, @client, @position)`

Comment: @Tomanow - sorry I can't help you because I dont know anything about rails. and I just add that comment to Fon.